# Sort list comparing only the first string from list of objects inside the initial list

Tags: java, spring, stream

I have a list of myDto objects

```
public class myDto {

    private String requestId;
    private List<Dogs> dogs;

}
```

I can sort the list comparing requestIds by

```
myDtoList.sort(Comparator.comparing(f -> f.getRequestId));
```

If the Dog object looks like this

```
public class Dog {

    private String name;    
}
```

Is it possible and how can I sort the initial list comparing only the first items from each dog's list? So no matter how many dogs are in the list to compare only the first dog entries in each myDto object.
Lets say I have myDtoList with 3 entries 1, 2 ,3 . 
Entry 1 has a dog named "Zoro" thats first in the list of dogs with many more.
Entry 2 has a dog named "Fancy" thats first in the list of dogs with many more.
Entry 3 has a dog named "Ann" thats first in the list of dogs with many more. 
After sorting they will revert to - entry 3, entry 2, entry 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you can get the first item's name via `getDogs().get(0).getName()`. If the list is allowed to be empty, you can do

```
getDogs() != null && getDogs().size() > 0 ? getDogs().get(0).getName() : null;
```

Use this instead of getRequestId().